# Create set of sets javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have a group of arrays that I need to filter out duplicates. It needs to work in such a fashion that within each array, there are no duplicates, and within the total group, there are no two arrays that hold the same values.

The first part is easy - for each inner array, I can apply `Set` to the array and filter it out. So, given the matrix `arrays` I can apply the following to filter:

```
const sets : string[][] = arrays.map(arr=>[...new Set(arr)].sort());
```

This will give me an array of sets. How can I make this into a set of sets? As in, if `sets=[[a, b],[c],[d, a],[c],[e]]` I would like `setOfSets` to equal `[[a, b],[c],[d, a],[e]]`?

Applying `setOfSets = [...new Set(sets)];` would not work, since arrays that are equal are not considered equal by default if they have different addresses. Is there a way to force `set` to check by value, or another effective way to create this effect?

**Edit**

Original matrix:

```
[[a, b, b],
[c,c],
[b,a],
[d,a],
[c,c],
[e,e]]
```

after creating and sorting sets:

```
[[a,b],
[c],
[a,b],
[d,a],
[c],
[e]]
```

desired  result:

```
[[a,b],
[c],
[d,a],
[e]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data in your set is easy to serialize, I would opt for a solution like this:

```js
const data = [
  ["a", "b", "b"],
  ["c","c"],
  ["b","a"],
  ["d","a"],
  ["c","c"],
  ["e","e"]
];

// Create the "hash" of your set
const serializeSet = s => Array
  .from(s)
  .sort()
  .join("___");

// Create a map (or object) that ensures 1 entry per hash
const outputMap = data
  .map(xs => new Set(xs))
  .reduce(
    (acc, s) => acc.set(serializeSet(s), s),
    new Map()
  );

// Turn your Map and Sets back in to arrays
const output = Array
  .from(outputMap.values())
  .map(s => Array.from(s));
  
console.log(output);
```

To come up with a good hash function for your set, you need to have a good look at your data. For example:

- When your arrays consist of single characters from a-z, like in my example above, we can `sort` those strings using a default sorter and then `join` the result *using a character from outside the a-z range*.
- If your arrays consist of random strings or numbers, `JSON.stringify(Array.from(s).sort())` is safer to use
- When your arrays consist of plain objects, you could `JSON.stringify` its sorted elements, but *watch out for differences in the order of objects properties! (e.g. `{a: 1, b: 2}` vs `{b: 2, a: 1}`)*

Comment: Ah, the examples were added when I was typing my answer. Thanks for the heads up. I'll have a look

Comment: @Wimanicesir I just tried it and my code does give the desired result?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `join("___")`?

Comment: When you create a hash of your data, there are often edge cases. The weird delimiter attempts to minimize those risks. For example, in my hashing function, there is the unsafe case of `["a___", "b"]` vs `["a", "___b"]` will both give `"a______b"` as a hash, so they will be incorrectly seen as duplicates. To create a hashing function that is safe to use, you need to know what your data might look like. In this case, when working with sample input, the `___` is enough.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the solution, but I will do some research. Thank you!

Comment: I'll add some examples to my answer. In the mean time: the most commonly used way of hashing your arrays would be by using `JSON.stringify`. Maybe that makes more sense: `serializeSet = s => JSON.stringify(Array.from(s).sort())`

Comment: when I try to write this line ` (acc, s) => acc.set(serializeSet(s), s)` I get the error that `property 'set' does not exist on type 'string[]'` (or `on type Set<string>` if I follow your code exacly). I am using typescript - can you please help me understand what exactly the reduce function is suppoed to do?

Comment: The `reduce` function _reduces_ your array of sets in to one single `Map`. The Map is like a dictionary of key value pairs of `string, Set`. For that reduce to work, you need to pass a function that adds a Set to the Map and returns it (`(acc, s) => acc.set(serialize(s), s)`) and an initial empty Map (`new Map()`).

Another way of doing it would be to convert to an array of entries first: `const setEntries = mySets.map(s => [ serialize(s), s ])` and then construct a map using those: `const uniqueSetMap = new Map(setEntries)`.

Comment: My guess is that you forgot the second parameter to `reduce`, the `, new Map()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226916/discussion-between-pmo1948-and-user3297291).